# SSSD: Multiple machines using a single LDAP bind

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, authentication, pam

I have configured [SSSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Security_Services_Daemon) on my company’s machines to authenticate against AD. We have approximately 15,000 machines that are going to be switched on to use SSSD. When we enabled SSSD, our network went haywire due to all the LDAP connections coming from a single machine.

My first question is, why is SSSD doing multiple LDAP binds on a single machine?

The second question: We have machines that act as servers. There are about 750 servers out of all 15,000 workstations. Can I configure the server to handle the LDAP binds and share that with the other machines that report to that server? This way only the I will have minimal LDAP binds compared to if I do LDAP binds from each machine.

Answer (score 2):

> My first question is, why is SSSD doing multiple LDAP binds on a single machine?

If you only use LDAP as an ID provider (directory service with information such as UIDs/GIDs/groups), that only needs one connection, bound using the server's "machine credentials" (or anonymous).

But if you also use LDAP as an *authentication* provider, then every authentication attempt causes a new LDAP bind, because that is literally how the auth provider verifies the password: it checks whether binding as that user succeeds or not.

So if it's the latter case, consider setting up and using Kerberos as the authentication provider. (AD and IPA already have it.)

Finally, make sure you are actually using the "sss", not "ldap", as your PAM and nsswitch modules. (There are two kinds of "ldap" modules: the newer comes with *nslcd* and uses a single connection, the older doesn't use any daemon and initiates a new LDAP connection for *every single thing*. Both are bad because they bypass SSSD, but the older one is especially bad in terms of server load.)

> Can I configure the server to handle the LDAP binds and share that with the other machines that report to that server?

Yes, but only if you configure the server to *actually be* an LDAP server.

Nearly all LDAP systems support replication. Configure several of those servers to host LDAP replicas (read-only should be enough), and configure SSSD on all workstations to contact the replicas instead of the main server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This helps a lot. How do I tell if I am using the newer ldap module tat uses nslcd?

Comment: You shouldn't be using either, as you already have SSSD ('sss' module) to do the same thing. Using 'sss' and 'ldap' is just...redundant. But in order to distinguish the two 'ldap' modules, I'd run `ldd /lib/libnss_ldap.so.2` or `ldd /lib/security/pam_ldap.so` – if it shows a long list of libraries (libldap, libssl) that's the old (bad) one. If it shows _only_ libc+vdso, that's the nslcd-based one.